# How to create UITableView section view with Corner radius

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I searched lot of post related to my questions on stack overflow and other developer sites but i am unable to find exact and fit answer for that.  I need to create section view of table with corner radius with out third party framework , similar like Grouped tableview styled in iOS 6.

Please help !!!

Want to like this
[image]

Comment: you would have to round the corners of the top / bottom cell ?

Comment: can you please provide screenshots, how exactly you want?

Comment: You need to create custom view and add it in header in viewforheader method,it works...

Comment: @SuhasPatil i added my screenshots with questions .

Comment: can show code as well?

Comment: Ok, will post my answer

Answer (score 13):

Helping out here: I believe you are looking for an effect where the entire section corner is rounded (please see the attached screen-shot).

You can get this by setting **tableview style** to **.insetGrouped**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style/insetgrouped

[image]

Comment: 'insetGrouped' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer

Comment: Is corner radius editable?

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [view fnForMakingRoundCorners];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    [label setText:@"Text"];
    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 50.0f;
}
```

for making round corners i have written  UIView category for all views as:

```
// For -> Rounded Corners
-(void)fnForMakingRoundCorners {

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

will look like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for help mate, but i need to change in bottom too. can you suggest for that.

Comment: welcome, in bottom too means? you want footer to table view?

Comment: setting footer is just another delegate method, the round corner view is the same as above

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the option will be adding a containerView(customView) inside the section header and do the corner radius settings on it.

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView *footerView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
UIView *customView = (UIView *)[footerView viewWithTag:888];

if(footerView == nil){ // using a non-registered header
   // initialize footerView
   // <FooterView initialized>
   footerView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   footerView.backgroundView = nil; 

   customView = [UIView new];
   customView.tag = 888;
   [customView layer].cornerRadius = 5;
   [footerView.contentView addSubview: customView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this for table view

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        let pathRef = CGMutablePath()
        let bounds = cell.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        cornerLayerWidth = bounds.width
        var addLine = false



        if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
            pathRef.__addRoundedRect(transform: nil, rect: bounds, cornerWidth: cornerRadius, cornerHeight: cornerRadius)
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 0 {
            pathRef.move(to: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
            pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY), radius: cornerRadius)
            pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
            pathRef.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
            addLine = true

            cell.backgroundColor = .white

        }
        else if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
            pathRef.move(to: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY))
            pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY), radius: cornerRadius)
            pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
            pathRef.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
        } else {
            pathRef.addRect(bounds)
            addLine = true
        }

        layer.path = pathRef
        layer.fillColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor

        if (addLine == true) {
            let lineLayer = CALayer()
            let lineHeight = 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
            lineLayer.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.size.height - lineHeight, width: bounds.size.width , height: lineHeight)
            lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
            layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
        }

        let testView = UIView(frame: bounds)
        testView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
        testView.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.backgroundView = testView
    }
```

in case you want to include the section header also then try below one

declare cornerLayerWidth as global variable

```
var cornerLayerWidth:CGFloat = 0.0

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        let pathRef = CGMutablePath()
        let bounds = cell.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        cornerLayerWidth = bounds.width
        var addLine = false



        if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
            pathRef.__addRoundedRect(transform: nil, rect: bounds, cornerWidth: cornerRadius, cornerHeight: cornerRadius)
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 0 {


        }
        else if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
            pathRef.move(to: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY))
            pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY), radius: cornerRadius)
            pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
            pathRef.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
        } else {
            pathRef.addRect(bounds)
            addLine = true
        }

        layer.path = pathRef
        layer.fillColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor

        if (addLine == true) {
            let lineLayer = CALayer()
            let lineHeight = 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
            lineLayer.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.size.height - lineHeight, width: bounds.size.width , height: lineHeight)
            lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
            layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
        }

        let testView = UIView(frame: bounds)
        testView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
        testView.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.backgroundView = testView
    }
```

and

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eMPOIListHeaderViewCell") as! eMPOIListHeaderViewCell

        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        let pathRef = CGMutablePath()
        let bounds =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cornerLayerWidth, height: 50)//cell.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

        pathRef.__addRoundedRect(transform: nil, rect: bounds, cornerWidth: cornerRadius, cornerHeight: cornerRadius)

        pathRef.move(to: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
        pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY), radius: cornerRadius)
        pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
        pathRef.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))



        layer.path = pathRef
        layer.fillColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor

             let lineLayer = CALayer()
            let lineHeight = 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
            lineLayer.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.size.height - lineHeight, width: bounds.size.width , height: lineHeight)
            lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
            layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)

        let testView = UIView(frame: bounds)
        testView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
        testView.backgroundColor = .clear

        cell.backgroundView = testView


        return cell

    }
```